# Disable Implementation of an Abstract Method

Tags: c#

I have a code below that has an Interface, abstract class and a class. I want to disable the implementation of the abstract method Print() in the FreeCustomer Class. Is this possible? Thank you very much.

```
    public interface ICustomer
    {
        string CustomerName { get; set; }
        double Amount { get; set; }
        string Print();
    }

    public abstract class Customer : ICustomer
    {
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
        public abstract string Print();
    }

    public class GoldCustomer : Customer
    {
        public override string Print() {
            return "You are a Gold Customer: " + CustomerName;
        }
    }

    public class FreeCustomer : Customer 
    {

    }
```

Comment: Where is the "Implementation" of the print() method ? it can't be in interface and its not in Abstract class, so what you want to disable ?

Comment: offtopic Why do you need the abstract class at all, can't you not just use the Interface

Comment: What does it mean to `disable implementation`? If you have abstract method you have to override it in derived classes period.

Comment: The FreeCustomer class would have a mandatory implementation of the print() method. I'm thinking if it is possible not to implement the print() method in the FreeCustomer Class.

Comment: If you disable it, what's going to happen when you pass a `FreeCustomer` instance to a method that expects an `ICustomer` or `Customer` and tries to call `Print()` on that instance?

Comment: @BoltClock, The print() method should be disabled in the FreeCustomer Class. I'm thinking other way than using an "IF" condition. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Even if it were possible, it would be a bad idea: Why do you want to implement only part of a contract?

It seems that you are having this issue because the `ICustomer` interface is trying to do too many different things (and thereby violates the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)).

If you don't always need, or want to implement, the `Print` method, then take it out of the interface, or move it into a separate interface.

Comment: I think you meant the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), not the SRP

Comment: @dcastro: I might not have been aware of the ISP at the time when I wrote the answer. But I think you're right, the ISP is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

The only case when a derived class does not need to implement abstract method of base class is when you declare the derived class as abstract as well.

As MSDN doc says [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx),
 "If a base class declares a member as abstract, that method must be overridden in any non-abstract class that directly inherits from that class. If a derived class is itself abstract, it inherits abstract members without implementing them."

So you may Declare FreeCustomer to be abstract and then need not implement print in there, although I don't see it serving any purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, do not declare the function as `abstract` in the base `Customer` class - instead use `public virtual`, and provide an **empty** implementation in the base class.

Then all you have to do is override it in the classes where you actually need the `Print()` functionality, in everything else it will do nothing (because the base implementation will be used). This means you can keep it on the interface.